# SE blog onebox image overflows

Tags: bug, chat, design, blog, onebox

When  [oneboxing SE blog post](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/3912752#3912752), the image overflows:

> [image: Screenshot of feeds' blog post]

The image is too tall, and there's a strange white border around it… (taken from the blog image)

When hovering over it, it becomes even more clear due to the dotted border.

The image on the blog should have margins, rather than white pixels, and the onebox image should have a max-height. The overflow in chat is only apparent when you hover over the post, showing the dotted border.

I'm on Safari 9, OS X 10.11.

Comment: No repro: http://i.stack.imgur.com/CF2Lr.png

Comment: What browser and OS?

Comment: @Andy Hover over it.

Comment: For you it's trivial, but having to hover is really not trivial for anyone else.

Comment: @Shadow It's visible without hovering, but it's obvious if you hover.

Comment: Nope, like @Andy said without hovering it looks just fine. (Unless you're really into those bugs in the first place and know exactly what to look for. Most people are not :))

Comment: @Shadow The onebox has a white background, the post has a grey background. The image overflows outside of the white rectangle and dangles into the surrounding grey rectangle.

Comment: @bjb568, not everyone has eyes as good as yours, or a monitor calibrated to be perfect or notices the difference between "white" and "almost white" at first glance. If you are posting a bug report, you need to be clear about what is wrong. "obvious" to you, is not "obvious" to all.

Comment: Reproed on Windows 10 Chrome latest version. +1

Comment: OK, fine, it's one of those "really hard to notice, but once you do, you can't  avoid seeing it" bugs.

Comment: Yep. Totally a bug.

Comment: @Andy Your first image is the very repro :D